# Should we advise people to avoid wording that sounds like a bad post?

Tags: discussion

We've all seen bad answers that started with "try this" and then tossed out an idea without any explanation or reasoning behind why it would work. Likewise, I'm sure plenty of you have seen posts that *seemed* like that at first but then turned out to be perfectly good answers that happened to use words that often signal a bad post. A similar problem can occur with answers that begin with saying "I have/had this problem too" but then go on to detail a good solution.

Given that a lot of people review quite quickly and carelessly, should we be advising users to avoid language that's liable to get them incorrectly marked as poor posts? In an ideal world everyone would pay attention, but since that's not happening at the moment, is it fair to police the wording of answers like this or is it unnecessary and overreaching?

Comment: Would love for any question that includes the word "best" to receive a warning on opinionated questions.

Comment: Basically: should we be advising people to change their ways to cope with other people who review carelessly. That doesn't sound right, the careless reviewers basically get a "get out of jail free" card here at the expense of people who are actually trying to be helpful.

Comment: What type of "reviewers" are you talking about? Like handling NAA?

Comment: You can advise people how to phrase questions to get better responses but some people might not have good enough English skills so that they can reword their questions to suit people who review too quickly and robotically to read questions fully and correctly.

Comment: @KevinB it is quite possible that system already works this way. A while ago I experimented with dumping copies of some troublesome questions into "Ask Question" boxes - system seemed to be pretty active at raising various context-dependent warnings (including something about "your question is likely to be closed as opinion based"). It is probably that some askers [ignore system advice](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6850/how-effective-is-the-quality-filter-against-this-question-with-all-caps-brief-ti?lq=1#comment19960_6854 "example: 'that guy was warned 15 times...'")

Comment: @codeMagic Reviews like that, also questions with 'Best' in them as Kevin B pointed out

Comment: I hate seeing both of those especially "I had the same problem" at the top of a post. But instead of trying to limit or warn with all of these different phrases, I think we need to work more on getting people to read the help center and handling bad reviewers. Those two issues are the root of a lot of problems.

Comment: @KevinB - *The best solution I have come up with so far still throws an exception. Here is the code for it. Here is the exception message. I was trying to foo the bar, but cannot figure out why the exception occurs.* This scenario would contain the word "best" but would include both the desired behavior and existing behavior in addition to error messages and a brief explanation of the overall process. I don't think it would be a bad post, and yet it would get a warning about opinionated questions? It is basically impossible to use one word as a signpost like that.

Comment: It's a warning, not a block. If it doesn't apply to you you can dismiss it. No solution will be perfect.

Comment: @KevinB - That seems awfully annoying. If I use the word "best" I have to deal with a large warning on the side that I need to click? Does it occur every time I type best? I just don't see this being worthwhile. I think a better option would be to have a question asking wizard for new users (which is in the works).

Comment: We already have a similar system in place for users who downvote frequently. You'll get a little popup suggesting that you leave a comment. To make it less annoying, it gets disabled after a certain rep amount. Many of us higher rep users were never exposed to it due to being above the threshold when it was introduced.

Comment: Personally, if the answerers were proven to write a good answer (even with "Try this" or "I have the same problem"), I'd either edit it or just ignore it. Honestly, the onus is on the reviewer who has "itchy finger" to instantly flag a post without reading the whole post.

Comment: If a busy reviewer gets a gut feeling that the post is a waste of time then so will a busy user. I'd suggest that it will work well if reviewers look for particular loophole wording and lack of phrases where the post puts its money where its keyboard is. This way busy users can have the same confidence and also answers will tend to be limited to those where the poster is not afraid that they will lose reputation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe there is already a fair amount of advice out there for instruction on how to properly compose a question on Stack Overflow. The onus of reading the material or simply understanding the format is on the user up front.

Once they begin composing their question or once it is finished, there is simply not enough information to say with certainty that their post would fall in one of the "sounds like a bad post" buckets.

Perhaps there would be a way to catch some percent of them, but that still leaves the remaining percent receiving a very annoying warning message with no reason. Not only would it annoy the users which did no deserve it, it would confuse many of them - potentially causing them to negatively alter their post.

I do not believe we should automatically detect and in turn advise people to avoid wording. The onus is on them to produce quality questions and do their research *before* composition.

The best automated effort towards improving posts from users is going to be the question wizard, but that is nowhere near completion and not even near the [6-8 week](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/165773) time window for consideration. In the mean time, anything which attempts to infer post quality by detecting one word or phrase is just not going to work.

Aside from automation, if as a user you observe a question which has several pitfalls included and are inclined to help, then editing the question would serve as the best way to offer such advice. Edit the question into a more appropriate shape and then leave a comment explaining why the pitfalls were removed. This will allow for the question to be in a state which should allow for being answered easier, and also will instruct the user on the common pitfall you observed and give them an example of how to remove it.

Comment: I think I didn't explain myself clearly, I wasn't thinking an automated system. I was wondering if us users should advise newer people about how their wording will sound incorrect. I also don't think the help centre addresses this because it's not a flaw in their question as much as it is an accidental similarity to bad questions, which is too ambiguous to give general guidelines to users on compared to commenting on specific posts that could have allowed SO users to make false assumptions.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan - I read it as automated at first. However, if that is not the intention then I edited in a paragraph at the bottom of the post. Basically, what it boils down to is that if you observe a question by a user which has accidentally worded their problem so that it is harder to answer, then edit it into shape and leave a comment explaining your edit to them.

Comment: I have a very, very tiny suggestion for this answer: I would say "before submitting" rather than "before composition." The reason being that the writing process very often reveals avenues of research or ideas you didn't consider before you began. Actively encouraging this process is good for users. It applies not only to writing prose, but also to writing code, and it's good to be aware that this is a reality and is a good way of doing things. That might be what you meant, but it doesn't quite read that way. Otherwise, +1.